# SQL Server temporal tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2017, temporal-tables

I have a SQL Server 2017 database, and I created a `Department` table as seen below

```
CREATE TABLE Department
(
    DeptID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    DeptName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    ManagerID INT NULL,
    ParentDeptID INT NULL,
    StartTime DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START
        CONSTRAINT DF_Department_SysStartTime DEFAULT SYSUTCDATETIME() NOT NULL,
    EndTime DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END
        CONSTRAINT DF_Department_SysEndTime 
        DEFAULT CONVERT( DATETIME2, '9999-12-31 23:59:59' ) NOT NULL,
    PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME(StartTime, EndTime)
)
WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.DepartmentHistory));
```

Next I inserted a row using the code below

```
INSERT INTO Department (DeptID, DeptName, DepartmentDescription)
VALUES (1, 'Sales', 'Sales department')
```

I ran a select on the `Department` table and `DepartmentHistory` table, `Department` contained the 1 row which I inserted but `DepartmentHistory` doesn't.

I ran an update as below, post the update the `DepartmentHistory` was populated with 1 row.

```
UPDATE Department 
SET DeptID = 2 
WHERE DeptID = 1
```

Do temporal tables not show Inserted rows?

Comment: You rather mean: do theyn ot show the current row. Now, why would they ;)

Comment: Why should they show the inserted rows since they already exists in the table? in other hand they will show deleted/updated rows.

Comment: so perhaps some more clarity, taking the example above, the DepartmentHistory shows the department id as 2 after the update, in truth Department 1 was the initial value which was changed to 2, so the problem is the History table is not recording the changes right from the insert. Is this an expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

This is all documented very well in the MS Docs: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-2017

**INSERTS:** 
On an INSERT, the system sets the value for the SysStartTime column to the begin time of the current transaction (in the UTC time zone) based on the system clock and assigns the value for the SysEndTime column to the maximum value of 9999-12-31. This marks the row as open.

**UPDATES:** 
On an UPDATE, the system stores the previous value of the row in the history table and sets the value for the SysEndTime column to the begin time of the current transaction (in the UTC time zone) based on the system clock. This marks the row as closed, with a period recorded for which the row was valid. In the current table, the row is updated with its new value and the system sets the value for the SysStartTime column to the begin time for the transaction (in the UTC time zone) based on the system clock. The value for the updated row in the current table for the SysEndTime column remains the maximum value of 9999-12-31.

Comment: I can still see how this could be confusing. Cause it says it marks the row as open and this could be read as the row in the history table thus, someone may expect to see that row there (thought his wouldn't be efficient at all)

Comment: @scsimon Right, but between the docs and the realworld example of it not showing up, the conclusion is pretty apparent.

Answer (score 0):

Yes new inserted column does not have a versioning unless it is changed. Once the values gets changed then it is updated in the history table because a version of the record generated.